# Contour gnuplot: how to add the name of variable to the labels of contours?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I'm writing my second paper with LaTeX, and most of my questions could be answered by many posts from this page. Firstly great thanks to you for that!

But one problem remained: I have a contour plot:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, headinclude, twoside=false, parskip=half, pagesize=auto, headings=normal, numbers=noenddot, open=right, toc=listof, toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9, 
    xlabel near ticks, 
    ylabel near ticks, 
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={\,}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        small,
        height=0.4\textwidth, 
        width=0.4\textwidth,
        domain=-1.414:1.414,
        enlargelimits=0.033,
        tick align=outside,
        tickpos=left,
        minor tick num=4,
        grid=major,
        xlabel=x-Achse,
        ylabel=y-Achse,
        view={0}{90},]
    \addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=14, label distance={30mm}},thick]
        {4742.16677745346-62.1338969789625*x+128.778340852979*0+1289.68038315857*y-14.32275*x*0-19.156499999999*x*y-23.728*0*y+168.504260966127*x^2-83.3735819705029*0^2-24.3633946025252*y^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\caption{Höhenliniendiagramm}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The pdf looks like this:

[image]

I want to add the name of a variable to the labels in a contour plot. On one contour line shall be written b=6000 instead of 6000 only. The other labels on the lines shall stay the same.

I have searched this page already, but all I found were proposals to make own labels for the contour lines. I hope there is an easier way to do this. I thought that this must be possible because this style is used a lot in diagrams I saw in books.